# FreeBSD + multithreaded python = *intermittent* failures to return from function [Ryzen incompatibility?]

Tags: python, multithreading, hardware, freebsd

[UPDATED: 'fix' is disable SMT in BIOS; i.e. something very ugly is going on: FreeBSD vs Ryzen]

This one has me scratching my head. The following code intermittently fails on FreeBSD 11.1 + python 3.6.4 + postgresql 10.1 + Ryzen 1600x. This is all happening inside of a Flask app, but I do not think that that is relevant.

The problem does not occur with this code with macOS + python 3.6.4 + postgresql 10.1.

The code does not seem to fail ever if `workers <= 4`. It will fail randomly if `workers >= 5`. It will take < 20 tries to induce a failure.

Success will yield the list of finds, of course. You will also see a copy of `finished search` for every worker: 4x, 6x, 10x, ... You will also see a single `RETURNED FROM SEARCH`.

Failure means you never get the list returned. But you will see a copy of `finished search` for every worker: 4x, 6x, 10x, ... And so `workonsearch()` really does seem to have completely finished. Nevertheless you will *not* see `RETURNED FROM SEARCH` as the result returns to `threadedsearcher()`

A stripped down version of the code in question:

```
def threadedsearcher(searchobject):

    managedlistoffinds = manager.list()
    searchlist = manager.list(searchobject.tosearch)

    workers = 6

    jobs = [Process(target=workonsearch, args=(managedlistoffinds, searchlist, lookingfor))
                for i in range(workers)]      
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
    print('RETURNED FROM SEARCH')
return managedlistoffinds


def workonsearch(managedlistoffinds, searchlist, lookingfor):

    dbconnection = setconnection()
    curs = dbconnection.cursor()
    so = searchobject

    while searchlist:
        try:
            table = searchlist.pop()
        except IndexError:
            table = None
            searchlist = None

        if table:
            newfinds = mysearch(lookingfor, table)
            managedlistoffinds += newfinds

    dbconnection.commit()
    curs.close()
    print('finished search')
    return managedlistoffinds
```

Comment: Do you have a limit on the number of connections with postgresql? that could explain why it falls over with larger numbers.

Comment: postgresql configuration seems like a promising avenue, but unfortunately maxconnections was 100 and raising it to 200 made no difference (even though not even 100 should have been used before).

Comment: a little more info: when killing the process the following will be seen: `Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 35, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
    KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: I wonder if you'll have the same problem using a `Queue` instead of a `manager` list.

Comment: You never close your `dbconnection` at the end. This isn't a problem by itself, but psycopg2 closes it for you in the `del` method, which would run after your print, so I'd try explicitly doing `dbconnection.close()` and `del dbconnection` before you print "finished search" to see if it's hanging on closing the DB connection.